Nginx load balancer: rewrite to $upstream_addr fails
I have 3 physical servers DOMAIN-A, DOMAIN-B and DOMAIN-C.
I created a load balancer in DOMAIN-A:
upstream backend {
  server DOMAIN-B:443 weight=3;
  server DOMAIN-C:443 weight=1;
}

server {

  server_name DOMAIN-A;

  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN-A/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN-A/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

  location / {
        proxy_pass https://backend;
        # rewrite / $scheme://$upstream_addr/ permanent;
  }
}

As it is, without the "rewrite", the load balancer chooses 1 of the 2 remote servers successfully, but the browser still shows the load balancer DOMAIN-A url and clicking on a page link still acts in DOMAIN-A (!!!).
What I want to achieve is to redirect permanently to the chosen DOMAIN-B or C.
I tried to rewrite to $upstream_addr (which should contain the IP of the domain chosen by the load balancer) but it seems it doesn't work:
rewrite / $scheme://$upstream_addr/ permanent;  <--- this doesn't work, gives redirect error
rewrite / $scheme://DOMAIN-B/ permanent; <--- this obviously works

How can I redirect the browser to the chosen domain?
